# operator * overload c++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to make a program that can opearate with complex numbers. However i got stuck with **operator *** I cannot figure out how to make these 2 cases work:

```
First:
c = 10 * d;
cout << c << endl;
Second:
c = d * 10;
cout << c << endl;
```

This is my header:

```
class Complex
{
    private:
        double Real, Imag;
    public:
        Complex() : Real(), Imag()
        {
        }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Complex (double Real)       //Initialization with only one variable
    {
        this->Real = Real;
        Imag = 0;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Complex (double Real, double Imag)      //Complete initialization
    {
        this->Real = Real;
        this->Imag = Imag;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Complex & operator = (const Complex &s)
    {
        Real = s.Real;
        Imag = s.Imag;
        return *this;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Complex operator * (Complex s)   // (r + i) * x
    {
        this->Real *= s.Real;
        this->Imag *= s.Real;
        return *this;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Complex & operator *= (Complex s)      //Reference
    {
        Real *= s.Real;
        Imag *= s.Imag;
        return *this;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    friend Complex operator * (Complex s1, Complex s2);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &s, const Complex &c)      
    {
        s << c.Real << " + " << c.Imag;
        return s;
    }
};
    //Out of class functions
    inline Complex operator * (Complex s1, Complex s2)      // x * (r + i)
    {
        s2.Real *= s1.Real;
        s2.Imag *= s1.Real;
        return s2;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    bool Complex::operator == (const Complex &s) const
    {
        return (this->Real == s.Real && this->Imag == s.Imag);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif /* __Complex_H__ */
```

My idea was to use operator inside class for second case, and outside for first case. But I got error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator*' in 'd * 10
```

How to make it clear to compiler which overload to use?

My main is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "complex.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Complex c, d(3, 5);
    c = 10 * d;
    cout << c << endl;
    c = d * 10;
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: What does your actual code look like? `c = 10 * d;` by itself won't compile.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but your `operator *` behaves exactly as `operator *=` which is not correct. And, why do you need, both, in-class overloads, and out of-class overloads? it seems that compiler can't decide which one to call.

Comment: My idea to make in and out class overloads was to make both of these cases work. I have no clue how to solve it within class

Comment: Also inside class method takes care of `complex * complex` case

Comment: @Aghero -- 1) Learn to pass objects by reference, not by value.  2) `Complex operator * (const Complex& s)  { return Complex(*this) *= s; }`  -- Reuse the already written operators, such as `*=`.  Writing functions "from scratch" increases the chance of errors.  3) You are missing `operator !=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the `friend` non-class method is invoked without ambiguity because first parameter is not a `Complex` but can be built as such using the `double` to `Complex` constructor

In the second case, member method `*` and `friend` function can be applied, hence the error.

There's no need for a friend operator using 2 `Complex` objects. It's only useful when first parameter is a non-class object / a class object where you cannot set/change the behaviour of `*`

You'd be better off with:

```
friend Complex operator * (double s1, const Complex &s2);
```

Notes:

- standard library has a very good `std::complex` implementation.
- it would be better to use constant references rather than value parameter passing
- overloading member `operator*(double s1)` would be interesting to avoid converting to a `Complex` when you want to multiply by a real value.

Comment: But the first parameter of the outside of class definition is a `Complex`?

Comment: Thank you, changing s1 from complex to double solved it. Also thanks for all advices

Comment: not sure to understand what you're asking. there's no need for a friend operator using 2 Complex objects. It's only useful when first parameter is a non-class object / a class object where you cannot set/change the behaviour of `*` (thx for the question, I have updated my answer accordingly)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True, but what I am asking is your first sentence, but maybe I am just understanding it wrong: "the `friend` non-class method is invoked without ambiguity because first parameter is not a `Complex` but can be built as such using the `double` to `Complex` constructor" So it is a `Complex` if the int can be converted implicitly to a `Complex` and the first parameter of the friend function is a `Complex`.

Comment: yes, but the choice has already been made by the compiler: friend method is a match so it builds Complex from double and calls it. It's the only valid path. It won't build an object to be able to call one of its member methods. It's too high-level.